# Can anyone transliterate this text?

Tags: mantras, translation-request, sanskrit, tantra

[image]

I got down the first part, it's *Om namo Bhagavate*. But the handwriting is confusing.

Comment: Transliteration questions are off-topic for the site.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> उों नमो भगवते श्री-उड्डामरेश्वराय अमुकं उच्चाटय २
>   विद्वेषय २ स्वाहा ।

The IAST transliteration of above mantra taken from [sanscript](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript):

> uoṃ namo bhagavate śrī-uḍḍāmareśvarāya amukaṃ uccāṭaya 2
>   vidveṣaya 2 svāhā ।

Comment: Thank you and peace

Comment: You don't know that transliteration Qs are off-topic? I guess this is the second time you have answered such a Q recently. And I'm even more surprised to see that you have voted to close a Q and at the same time answered it.

Comment: @Rickross Yeah I had forgotten. Knowing that, I casted cv.

Answer (score 2):

I will try:

Om Namo bhagavate shri-uddaamaresvaraya amukang ucchaataya  2
Vidveshaya 2 svaha.